# Array values to cells

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, cell-array

I have google script for changing text in rows. Problem after text modification is that I do not know how to save array values to cells in second sheet.

```js
// Array to cells

function textReplaceLoop2() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var ss1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var ss2 = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

 
 // reading valies and couting number of rows 
 var arraytexttomod = ss1.getRange(2,1,ss1.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
 var numofrowsfix = arraytexttomod.length -1 ;
 Logger.log(numofrowsfix);

  var arraymod = new Array;

// loop text modification
  for (var i = 0 ; i < numofrowsfix ; i++ ) {
  var textmodread = arraytexttomod[i];
  textmodmod = textmodread.toString().replaceAll(".", "");

  //Logger.log(textmodmod);
  arraymod[i] = textmodmod;
   
}

Logger.log(arraymod);  
ss2.getRange(2,1).setValues([arraymod]);  // NOT WORKING,  ONLY WORKING FOR COLUMNS WITH RANGE (2,1,1,132) BUT NOT FOR ROWS 
}
```

log:
[image]

Comment: You probably need to use the 4 params versions of the sheet.getRange. The ss2.getRange(2,1) is looking for 1 cell only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want it as a column, try this:

```js
const col = arraymod.map(value => [value]);
ss2.getRange(2, 1, col.length, col[0].length).setValues(col);
```

Comment: Thank you, but not working> Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

Comment: can you log out `arraymod` and paste the values in the question please?

Comment: It seems to me that my array is how to say simple. And I need the multidimensional... not sure. I do to know how to convert array to multidimensional array

Comment: just post what it looks like please

Comment: now there is correct log

Comment: ok, it's a one-dimensional array. how do you need it formatted? as a column? as a row? like something else?

Comment: assuming that you want the data as a column, I updated my answer

Comment: Yes, column. Thank you.